# How can I make all external links to open in a new tab?

Tags: theming

I want to create a small, custom Drupal 8 module to open all external links in the menu in a new tab, how can I do that?

I think I should use `hook_link_alter` to do it, but I don't know how to do it so I can select all the external links only?

Comment: Do you want all the external links, or only the ones in the menu?

Comment: Not an answer but out of interest, what would the general opinion be of using jQuery to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Links can be generated in a number of ways, which makes it hard to change consistently. For a single implementation that you want to reach most parts, you should swap the `link_generator` service with your own subclass. This should catch all menu items and links in general, but wont touch custom markup from wysiwyg. Here you would need to create a custom filter.

The `::generate($text, Url $url)` method is what is used to actually create the create the HTML. What you want to do, it to add the `_blank` target attribute if the url is external.

The code for the link generator subclass, could look like this:

```
class MyLinkGenerator extends LinkGenerator {
  public function generate($text, Url $url) {
    if ($url->isExternal()) {
      $attributes = $url->getOption('attributes');
      $attributes['target'] = '_blank';
      $url->setOption('attributes', $attributes);
    }
    return parent::generate($text, $url);
  }
}
```

I wont go into how to change the class of a service, there is plenty of examples for this here and elsewhere.

Comment: For the changing of the class of a service, I would advise this link: https://www.hs2solutions.com/blog/drupal-how-override-core-drupal-8-service

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use hook_link_alter you can also simply implement the following code in a module :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_link_alter().
 */
function mymodule_link_alter(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['options']['external'] == TRUE) {
    $vars['options']['attributes']['target'] = '_blank';
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to implement a module with the above code, but it crashes. I get a 'Notice: Undefined index: external' on the line of the if-statement. Searching around, I found a similar question (id: 213292). It has a nearly identical code, but the if-statement becomes: 'if ($vars['url']->isExternal())'. If I substitute the if-statement with the one found, code now doesn't crash but it does absolutely nothing. I tried clearing caches, also tried with external links in menu, in content type (via link field) and in the body of a basic page. It does nothing, link opens in same tab. Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

[extlink](https://www.drupal.org/project/extlink) contrib module for Drupal 8 & 9 (also a D7 version) can do the job.

On the [extlink contrib module project page](https://www.drupal.org/project/extlink) it says:

> Configure external links to open in a new window

And there is other functionality, too.

I've just started using this module and from tests so far, it does the job.

In my case it does actually open an external link in a **new tab** so even though it says new window, it actually opens in a new tab.